# MVC 3 Custom Login Scheme

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am wanting to develop an MVC 3 application which stores user data and allows them to login, then view that data, view friends data.

The issue seems to be that MVC limits you with the default login from the templated file.

Does anyone know of a good tutorial or book which focuses on developing a custom login scheme for the data base. For example, I would like to be able to have users login and store their information (encrypted ) in the DB.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [ASP.NET Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx) & Forms Authentication for your authentication system.

This is easy to [setup in conjunction with a SQL Server DB](http://www.asp.net/general/videos/how-do-i-set-up-the-sql-membership-provider), has built in mechanisms to securely hash or encrypt passwords, uses a cookie based authentication token to identify users, and it has a role Based Access Control (RBAC) system that is nicely integrated into ASP.NET. For example RBAC can be used in web.config to deny access to paths with your site:

eg.

```
<configuration>
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="Administrator" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
</configuration>
```

You also have the [Authorize] attribute which you can sprinkle around your Action methods:

```
[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]
public ActionResult AdminPage()
{
    return View();
}
```

If you wanted a really simple solution with no Roles, and perhaps no SQL Server DB, you can also just use straight [ASP.NET Forms Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t6b43z4.aspx) without ASP.NET Membership. However, for any real world application, ASP.NET Membership is a more complete solution.

Note that you do not have to use the the authentication code in the Account controller or the Account Model in the default MVC3 application. These are overkill in my opinion.

Whatever you do, don't re-invent the wheel. Authentication and role based access control is not trivial to get right, which is why you should be using the built in solution in ASP.NET.

See also [this MVC tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-forms-authentication-cs).

Comment: Ok, so I have a database schema setup. How do I incorporate the default account model that is created by default when you make an mvc3 app. When a user creates an account (using default account setup in MVC 3) I want the user account to be the primary in my database relation. Does that make sense?